# bxSlider não faz reload quando se clica no seu parent escondido

Tags: jquery, bxslider

Olá

Tenho um slideshow que usa o bxSlider e que se encontra dentro de um DIV escondido ao carregar a página. Este bxSlider inicia-se noutra função que escrevi abaixo.

Tenho entretanto um botão para fazer aparecer todo o conteudo escondido mas o slideshow fica sempre escondido.

Estou a usar o método reloadSlider do bxSlider mas não resulta.

E o codigo html do slideshow dentro do div escondido:

```
<div class="row">
<article class="container-fluid hiddenDiv">
    <aside id="slideshowContainer" class="col-xs-12 noPadding">
        <ul class="col-xs-12 noPadding">
            @foreach (var slide in slideshow)
            {
                var isVideo = slide.GetString("ItemPublisher:Item.TypeOfMedia") == "Video";
                var title = slide.GetString("ItemPublisher:Item.Title");
                var slideLink = !isVideo ? (slide.GetString("ItemPublisher:Item.Link").IsNotNullOrEmpty() ? slide.GetString("ItemPublisher:Item.Link") : "javascript:void(0)") : slide.GetString("ItemPublisher:Item.Embed").IsNotNullOrEmpty() ? slide.GetString("ItemPublisher:Item.Embed") : "javascript:void(0)";
                var text = slide.GetString("ItemPublisher:Item.Text");
                var target = slide.GetBoolean("ItemPublisher:Item.OpenInNewWindow") ? "_blank" : string.Empty;
                var videoId = slideLink.Substring(slideLink.LastIndexOf('/') + 1);
                var imagePath = slide.GetString("ItemPublisher:Item.Image");
                var imageVideoPath = string.Concat("https://img.youtube.com/vi/", videoId, "/0.jpg");
                var hasImagePath = imagePath.IsNotNullOrEmpty();
                var image = Images.GetImage(hasImagePath ? imagePath : imageVideoPath, 1270, hasImagePath ? 0 : 640);

                <li>
                    <a @(isVideo ? "class=\"fancybox\"" : string.Empty) href="@slideLink" target="@target">
                        @if (isVideo)
                        {
                            @RenderIcon("fa-play-circle slideshowVideoIcon")
                        }
                        <div class="col-sm-4 hidden-xs slideText hidden">
                            @if (title.IsNotNullOrEmpty())
                            {
                                <h2>@title</h2>
                            }
                            @text
                        </div>
                        @RenderImage(ImageSettings.CreateImage(image, title))
                    </a>
                </li>
            }
        </ul>
        <div class="bx-pager">
            <ul>
                @{
                    var count = 0;
                    foreach (var slide in slideshow)
                    {
                        var isVideo = slide.GetString("ItemPublisher:Item.TypeOfMedia") == "Video";
                        var title = slide.GetString("ItemPublisher:Item.Title");
                        var slideLink = !isVideo ? (slide.GetString("ItemPublisher:Item.Link").IsNotNullOrEmpty() ? slide.GetString("ItemPublisher:Item.Link") : "javascript:void(0)") : slide.GetString("ItemPublisher:Item.Embed").IsNotNullOrEmpty() ? slide.GetString("ItemPublisher:Item.Embed") : "javascript:void(0)";
                        var videoId = isVideo ? slideLink.Substring(slideLink.LastIndexOf('/') + 1) : "";
                        var imagePath = slide.GetString("ItemPublisher:Item.Image");
                        var imageVideoPath = string.Concat("https://img.youtube.com/vi/", videoId, "/0.jpg");
                        var hasImagePath = imagePath.IsNotNullOrEmpty();
                        var image = Images.GetImage(hasImagePath ? imagePath : imageVideoPath, 450, hasImagePath ? 0 : 150);
                        <li>
                            <a data-slide-index="@count.ToString()" href="">@RenderImage(ImageSettings.CreateImage(image, title))</a>                               
                        </li>
                        count++;
                    }
                }
            </ul>
        </div>
    </aside>
</article>
</div>
<article class="container-fluid">
    <a class="toggleContentControl"</a>   
</article>
```

Eis o meu código JS:

```
function groupSection() {
var $hiddenDiv = $(".hiddenDiv ").parents("div.row").hide();
var $toggleBtnControl = $(".toggleContentControl");
var mySlider = $('#slideshowContainer> ul').bxSlider();

$toggleBtnControl.click(function (e) {
    var $this = $(this);
    var $text = $this.text();
        e.preventDefault();
    $hiddenDiv.slideToggle("fast", function () {
        $(this).find(".hiddenDiv ").slideToggle("fast"); 
        mySlider.reloadSlider();
    });
    $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: 200 }, "slow");
    $this.text($text == "More Information" ? "Less Information" : "More Information");
    })
}
```

E o codigo JS onde o bxSlider está a ser iniciado:

```
function onLoadPageSlideshow() {
if ($("#slideshowContainer").length) {
    $('#slideshowContainer> ul').bxSlider({
        pagerCustom: '.bx-pager',
        slideMargin:0,
        autoReload:true,
        controls:false
    });
    if ($(".bx-pager").length) {
        $('.bx-pager > ul').bxSlider({
            slideMargin: 0,
            autoReload: false,
            infiniteLoop: false, 
            pager: false,
            controls: true,
            breaks: [
                {screen: 0, slides: 2, pager: false},
                {screen: 460, slides: 3},
                {screen: 768, slides: 6}
            ]
        });
    }
}
```

}

Provavelmente não tou a chamar correctamente o bxSlider de novo. O que poderei fazer para este se abrir quando se mostra o conteudo?

Comment: Só com essas informações fica impossível dizer alguma coisa. Mostre alguma coisa do HTML e especifique mais o problema de forma que fique mais clara.

Comment: Vc só deve utilizar o `.reloadSlider()` caso adicione de forma dinâmica algum novo item no slider.

Comment: Editei a minha pergunta com o codigo html. Então, se eu não estou a adicionar um novo item ao slideshow, que método deverei utilizar para que este volte a carregar?

Comment: Ao iniciar o componente. Vc usa as coisas sem ver a documentação?

Comment: Vi a documentação e esqueci-me de explicar que o bxSlider é iniciado noutra função. Actualizei o código com essa função. Entretanto não deverei de alguma forma recarregar o BxSlider no evento "click" que mencionei acima?

Comment: Actualizei o código relativo a este assunto. Alguém poderá dar uma ajuda?